# Find Two Largest Numbers, C++

Tags: c++, arrays, compare

I'm using this approach: First find the largest among 5 numbers then save the subscript of array of the largest number in an "ivariable" after displaying the largest number, do like this
`array[ivariable] = 0 ;` 
so that first largest set to zero and its no longer here in the array.
And do the same again, find the largest, but I'm not getting what I'm trying to.
Its a logical error.
Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    int counter, large,number,det_2, i , large3, det_3= 0;
    int det[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};

    for(int k(0); k < 5 ; k++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the number  " << endl ;
        cin >> det[k] ;
    }

    for( i; i<5; i++)
    {
        large = det[i] ;
        if (large > det_2)
        {
            det_2= large ;
            counter = i ;
        }
        else 
        {

        }
    }
    cout << "Largest among all is  " << det_2 << endl;
    det[i] = 0 ;

    for( int j(0); j<5; j++)
    {
        large3 = det[j] ;
        if(large3 > det_3)
        {
            det_3= large3 ;                  
        }
        else 
        {

        }
    }
    cout << "Second largest  " << large3 << endl ;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: One problem is that you don't initialize `det_2` before comparing against it.

Comment: Look up [std::max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Comment: what do you expect the comparison result for `large > det_2` where `det_2` holds garbage value

Comment: I would suggest to use `qsort`.
See the example of [qsort reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/).

Comment: A side note: `else { }` (with an empty statement block) is useless and only makes your code more verbose. You can remove it.

Comment: Your algorithm runs over the sequence twice and modifies it in place in a destructive way. It is not hard to devise an algorithm that does a single pass, and does not involve destructive changes. Writing the optimal algorithm in number of comparisons is a bit more complex though...

Comment: @MarkkuK. yes i didn't initialize Separately

Comment: @sansix yes  you were right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got possible syntax and initialization errors.  Fix those first:

`for(int k(0); k < 5 ; k++)`:  I've never seen an integer initialized this way.  Shouldn't it be:

`for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)` ?  (Same with the last loop.)

Also,

`for( i; i<5; i++)`

The variable `i` is uninitialized.  Variables are not initialized to any default value in C++.  Because you've left it uninitialized, it might execute 5 times, no times, or 25,899 times.  You don't know.

This should be:

`for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)`

But the whole thing could probably be a bit clearer anyway:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    int largest = -1;
    int second_largest = -1;

    int index_of_largest = -1;
    int index_of_second_largest = -1;

    int det[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the number  " << endl;
        cin >> det[i];  // assuming non-negative integers!
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)  // find the largest
    {
        if (det[j] >= largest)
        {
            largest = det[j];
            index_of_largest = j;
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)  // find the second largest
    {
        if (k != index_of_largest) // skip over the largest one
        {
            if (det[k] >= second_largest)
            {
                second_largest = det[k];
                index_of_second_largest = k;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Largest is " << largest << " at index " << index_of_largest << endl;
    cout << "Second largest is " << second_largest <<
            " at index " << index_of_second_largest << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes the problem was i didn't initialize each variable separately

Answer (score 1):

Always give your variables values before you use them

```
det_2 = det[0];
counter = 0;
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
```

Comment: Yes i will be careful about this in future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- first problem I saw was that you are iterating using i as an index, but you don't initialize i.

code should be:

```
    for(i = 0; i<5; i++)
         ^^^^
```

- same goes for `det_2`. You compare elements against it, but do not initialize it. You should set it to `det[0]` before the loop where you use it.
- third problem: Your "set largest value to zero after printing" sounds like it is there so that you can apply the same algorithm the second time.

You should create an additional function that gives you the index of the largest element, and call it like this:

```
int index = find_largest_index(a);
cout << "largest element: " << a[index] << endl;
a[index] = 0;
cout << "second largest element: " << a[ find_largest_index(a) ] << endl;
```

Comment: Yes sometimes unfortunate preference can lead to unexpected results what i did is didn't initialize each variable separately.

Answer (score 0):

GCC 4.7.3: g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x largest.cpp

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Enter 5 numbers: ";

  // Read 5 numbers.
  std::vector<int> v;
  for (auto i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    int x = 0;
    while (!(std::cin >> x)) {
      // Error. Reset and try again.
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore();
    }
    v.push_back(x);
  }

  // partition on element 3 (4th number)
  std::nth_element(std::begin(v), std::next(std::begin(v), 3), std::end(v));

  std::cout << "Two largest are: ";
  std::copy(std::next(std::begin(v), 3), std::end(v), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Comment: I think you're using linked list data structure approach? right?

Comment: @ArsalaKamal, what makes you think that? I am using a container, but it is not a linked list, it is a vector (array).

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case of 5 elements, the algorithm you use is unlikely to make any real difference.

That said, the standard algorithm specifically designed for this kind of job is `std::nth_element`.

It allows you to find the (or "an", if there are duplicates) element that would end up on position N if you were to sort the entire collection.

That much is pretty obvious from the name. What's not so obvious (but is still required) is that `nth_element` also arranges the elements into two (or three, depending on how you look at it) groups: the elements that would short before that element, the element itself, and the elements that would sort after that element. Although the elements are not sorted inside of each of those groups, they are arranged into those groups -- i.e., all the elements that would sort before it are placed before it, then the element itself, then the elements that would sort after it.

That gives you exactly what you want -- the 4<sup>th</sup> and 5<sup>th</sup> elements of the 5 you supply.

As I said originally, in the case of just 5 elements, it won't matter much -- but if you wanted (say) the top 50000 out of ten million, choosing the right algorithm would make a much bigger difference.

Answer (score 0):

`nth_element` isn't always suitable (or as efficient as it could be) as it needs to rearrange the input elements.

It's very common to want just the top two elements, and can be done efficiently in one pass by keeping the best and second-best values seen so far, and whenever a value you iterate over is better than the second-best, you'll either replace the second-best with it or the best, and in the latter case you also overwrite the best with the new value.  That can look like this:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename It, typename EndIt, typename Less = std::less<>>
auto top_two(It it, EndIt end, Less less = Less{}) -> std::pair<It, It>
{
    It first = it;
    if (it == end || ++it == end)
        return {first, end};
    std::pair<It, It> results = less(*it, *first) ? std::pair{first, it} : std::pair{it, first};
    while (++it != end)
        if (less(*results.second, *it))
            results.second = less(*results.first, *it)
                             ? std::exchange(results.first, it) : it;
    return results;
}
```

(See it running at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7fa0c9f1945b3fe)

I return iterators so the caller can know where in the input the top two elements are, should they care (e.g. to erase them from a container, or calculate their distance from begin(), or modify their values).

It you want the two lowest values, just pass `std::greater<>{}` as your "less" argument.

Some convenience functions to make it easier to call with containers or `initializer_list`s:

```
template <typename Container, typename Less = std::less<>>
auto top_two(const Container& c, Less less = Less{})
{
    return top_two(begin(c), end(c), less);
}

template <typename T, typename Less = std::less<>>
auto top_two(const std::initializer_list<T>& il, Less less = Less{})
{
    return top_two(begin(il), end(il), less);
}
```

---

If you want a general solution for the top-N elements, it's better to make N an argument and create a multiset of N top values (using a dereferencing comparison type), putting the initial N elements in, then whenever a new element is more than the `**top_n.begin()` value, do a `top_n.insert(it);` followed by `top_n.erase(top_n.rbegin());` to drop the worst element: these operations are O(log N) so remain reasonably efficient even in pathological cases, such as input that is incrementing numbers.